# Select rows from last few minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

I want to achieve this function to select rows from the last few minutes. (Assuming the latest time is 09:34:00)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cur_time,108) as CUR_TIME, AVG(CAST(now_price AS FLOAT)) AS now_price 
FROM dbo.ticktest
GROUP BY CUR_TIME
HAVING CUR_TIME >= '09:32:30'
```

But I want it can automatically find the latest `cur_time` in my table, so I write this function in this way:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),cur_time,108) as CUR_TIME, AVG(CAST(now_price AS FLOAT)) AS now_price
FROM dbo.ticktest
GROUP BY CUR_TIME
HAVING CUR_TIME >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(mi,-1,MAX(cur_time)),108)
```

which returns data from all the period. So, how can I correct this mistake to make the function run properly.

Thanks

Comment: Please show some sample data and desired results, and tell us the datatype of `CUR_TIME`

Comment: Btw, I doubt you want to cast your money value to float, more likely decimal. Otherwise you will get unexpected rounding errors.

Comment: `HAVING` should only be applied if you need to filter on an **aggregated** column (`HAVING SUM(...) > 0`) - in your case, since you're **not** filtering on an aggregation, just use `WHERE` instead (and put that before the `GROUP BY`)

Comment: It's true that I didn't make it clear and the name can cause some misunderstandings, but the problem has been solved. Thanks for your comments anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sub query where you always pick the max time which is actually latest time

```
HAVING CUR_TIME >= (select max(CUR_TIME) from dbo.ticktest)
```